# When selenium test runs by Jenkins and MSUnit, the browser doesn't come up however there are valid results

Tags: selenium, jenkins

I put together a machine (Windows Server 2012R2) for POC reasons where a Jenkins installed and it executes Selenium UI tests using msunit

But, when I log in the server where the Jenkins runs and I watch what happens during CI build (compile and test execution) I can't see that the browser (Firefox) starts automatically, however, the test results and the logs show that a browser was executed.

My question is that, what the is happening when my tests are executed by Jenkins? If I execute the command which from visual studio on the same machine then I can see that Firefox starts, does what is programmed in the tests and the results are in the result.trx.Can I somehow set up Jenkins the way the browser really executed (I can believe it when I see it :)

Comment: can you tell if you are using any plugin for running or just the command to execute these tests?

Comment: ya i am using MSTest plugin ,tests are running and result of the tests are seen in build logs but the browser is not opening..no idea how its executing

Comment: you must be using MSTestRunner Plugin because MSTest Plugin only used to convert the result file TRX to JMX file.

Comment: sorry... i am using MSTestRunner Plugin

Answer (score 0):

In Jenkins when you run selenium test cases, they are executed in the background by default.

Your Jenkins might be configured to run those test cases in some video buffer(usually it happens on Linux but can also be configured on Windows) or in a headless state.

As your question, if you are using MSTest which basically used to convert the test cases result from trx to JMX format but also can be used to run selenium tests. when you run the same in Jenkins it will run in background on any slave or on master.

Comment: i am using MSTestRunner Plugin....how can i run the test from jenkins so that i can see the see browser opens automatically

Comment: sorry but you cannot see it actually. it will run in background or in headless state.

Comment: is their any other way?

Comment: Sorry but no other way.

Comment: So the browser running the test cannot be seen it seems

Comment: yes as the test cases are executed by Jenkins which basically runs them in background. so you only get to see the test reports. There is no difference with the test reports, it executes them same as it executes on your machine.

Comment: ok but i wanted to see the browser open..if any idea you get please tell me